# CD Web App SmartTarget Issue

Tags: smarttarget, ambient-data-framework

When my web app is trying to connect to the ST webservice, i'm getting the following error:

> ```
>   <StackTrace><![CDATA[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.smarttarget.webservice.WebServiceExecutor
>   at com.tridion.smarttarget.triggers.TriggerTypesHelper.getTriggerTypes(TriggerTypesHelper.java:73)
>   at com.tridion.smarttarget.triggers.TriggerTypesHelper.getTriggerTypes(TriggerTypesHelper.java:58)
>   at com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.TriggerTypesProcessor.loadTriggers(TriggerTypesProcessor.java:67)
>   at com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.TriggerTypesProcessor.onRequestStart(TriggerTypesProcessor.java:50)
>   at com.tridion.ambientdata.Engine.onRequestStart(Engine.java:147)
>    at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
>    at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
>    at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
>    at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallVoid(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
>    at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.Engine.OnRequestStart(ClaimStore claimStore)
>    at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart(HttpApplication
> ```
>
> application, HttpContext context, ClaimStore claimStore, Set
>   templateReadOnlyClaims, Set templateImmutableClaims, Set
>   templateSessionScopeClaims)]]>
>       
>       Stacktrace:
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.smarttarget.webservice.WebServiceExecutor
>         at com.tridion.smarttarget.triggers.TriggerTypesHelper.getTriggerTypes(TriggerTypesHelper.java:73)
>         at com.tridion.smarttarget.triggers.TriggerTypesHelper.getTriggerTypes(TriggerTypesHelper.java:58)
>         at com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.TriggerTypesProcessor.loadTriggers(TriggerTypesProcessor.java:67)
>         at com.tridion.smarttarget.ambientdata.TriggerTypesProcessor.onRequestStart(TriggerTypesProcessor.java:50)
>         at com.tridion.ambientdata.Engine.onRequestStart(Engine.java:147)
>          at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
>          at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
>          at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
>          at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallVoid(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
>          at Com.Tridion.Ambientdata.Engine.OnRequestStart(ClaimStore claimStore)
>          at Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData.Runtime.AmbientRuntime.OnRequestStart(HttpApplication
>   application, HttpContext context, ClaimStore claimStore, Set
>   templateReadOnlyClaims, Set templateImmutableClaims, Set
>   templateSessionScopeClaims)
>       2015-05-01 13:40:56,380 ERROR AmbientRuntime - Setting status code:500
>       2015-05-01 13:40:56,380 ERROR AmbientRuntime - Setting status code:500

While this looks like a missing jar, i've checked and rechecked the installation for jars / third-party jars and it all seems to be correct / nothing missing.

I've also checked that my trigger types file doesn't contain any errors (which it doesn't as i can create promotions in the cms etc).

So where is it going wrong?...

In my ambient data config i'm using the ST cartridge:

When this attempts to wire up the ADF to ST, I receive the error message above.

I'm running 2013 sp1 hr1 / ST 2014 sp1.

Has anyone any suggestions as to what this issue could be / how better to debug it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems that the documentation and the 'third-party' libs provided by the SmartTarget installation don't mention the file 'jersey-core.jar' which is needed and why there was a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in the code.

Thanks to Peter Kjaer for helping me resolve this, you're a good man peter x